# how to bind image list in to mudblazor table in .net blazor web assembly app

Tags: blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have an image list and i have to bind those list in to a mud table with delete icon.I am unable to bind the image in a mud-table

currently i have binded in a "Mud paper"

```
<MudPaper class="d-block pa-2 mud-theme-dark" >
                                @foreach (var item in saveFile?.Files)
                                {
                                    <MudPaper Class="pa-2 mx-2">
                                    <MudIconButton Color="Color.Error" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" OnClick="@(_ => RemoveImg(item))" aria-label="delete"></MudIconButton>
                                    <MudImage Width="150" Height="150" Src="@($"data:{item.FileType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(item.ImageBytes)}")" Alt="Mony the dog" Elevation="25" Class="rounded-lg" />
                                    </MudPaper>
                                }
                            </MudPaper>
```

I have tried below code but delete and bind is not working pls help me on this.

```
<MudTable Items="saveFile.Files" Hover="true" Striped="true" Dense="true" Class="mb-2">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Images</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Action</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Image"><MudAvatar Image="@context.Image" /></MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Edit">
         <MudIconButton Color="Color.Error" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" OnClick="@(_ => RemoveImg("what to pass here in table?"))" aria-label="delete"></MudIconButton>
        </MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>
```

below is my component code(razor .cs code)

```
 SaveFile saveFile = new SaveFile();
       
        private async Task UploadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles())
            {

                var fileData = new Image();
                var buffers = new byte[file.Size];
                await file.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffers);
                fileData.FileName = file.Name;
                fileData.FileSize = file.Size;
                fileData.FileType = file.ContentType;
                fileData.ImageBytes = buffers;
                saveFile.Files.Add(fileData);
            
            }
        }

        private void RemoveImg(Image file)
        {
            saveFile.Files.Remove(file);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use MudSelect

```
<MudSelect @bind-Value="selectedIndex" Label="@($"Selected Item (index: {selectedIndex})")">
@{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var item in _source)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="@index">@item</MudSelectItem>

        index++;
    }
}
```

```
private async Task DeleteAsync(int index)
{
    if (_source.Any())
    {
        _source.RemoveAt(index);
        await Task.Delay(1);
        _carousel.MoveTo(System.Math.Max(System.Math.Min(index, _source.Count - 1), 0));
    }

}
```